# Does the security level of the hash of multiple files differ with different approaches?

Tags: cryptography

I have the task of calculating the hash from multiple files.
I also already know the hash from each individual file.

There are two approaches:

1. `hash(f1 + f2 + f3)`
2. `hash(hash(f1) + hash(f2) + hash(f3))`

In the second approach, there will be less computation since I know the hash of each file individually.

Is the security level of these two approaches different?
Which of these approaches is more secure?

I am not strong in cryptography, so I can not objectively calculate the security level of each approach.

Answer (score 2):

TL,DR: use `hash(hash(f1) + hash(f2) + hash(f3))`

Note: in this answer, `+` means concatenation. It is never any kind of numerical addition. If you have numerical data, apply my answer after converting the data to byte strings.

There is a problem with `hash(f1 + f2 + f3)`: you can (for example) move some data from the end of `f1` to the beginning of `f2`, and that won't change the hash. Whether this is a problem depends on what constraints there are, if any, on the file formats and on how the files are used.

It's usually hard to make sure in a system design that this isn't a problem. So whenever you combine strings or files for hashing, you should always make sure the combination is unambiguous. There are a few different ways to do it, such as:

- Use some existing format that handles the packing of the strings or files for you. For example zip, ASN.1 DER, etc.
- Encode each part in a way that doesn't contain a certain byte, and use that byte as a separator. For example encode each part in Base64 and use line breaks as separators.
- Define a maximum length for each part. Before each part, encode the length using a fixed-width encoding. For example, if the maximum length of a part is 2^64-1 bytes, encode the unambiguous concatenation of `(f1, f2, f3)` as:

  - 8 bytes: `length(f1)`
  - `length(f1)` bytes: `f1`
  - 8 bytes: `length(f2)`
  - `length(f2)` bytes: `f2`
  - 8 bytes: `length(f3)`
  - `length(f3)` bytes: `f3`

If you instead take hashes of hashes, you don't run into this problem, because here you do have a very strong constraint on the strings you're concatenating: they have a well-defined length (whatever the length of the hash algorithm is).

Taking hashes of hashes does not degrade security. It's part of a well-known technique: [hash trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). If `hash(hash(f1) + hash(f2) + hash(f3)) = hash(hash(g1) + hash(g2) + hash(g3))` then `f1 = g1` and `f2 = g2` and `f3 = g3`.

In addition to making the construction and verification easier, this approach lets you save computation if the set of files changes. If you've already stored `hash(f1)` and `hash(f2)` and you want to add `f3` to the list, you just need to calculate `hash(f3)`, and then the hash of the new list of hashes. This is also very useful for synchronization of data sets. If Alice wants to transmit files to Bob, she can send the hashes first, then Bob verifies which hashes he already knows and tells Alice, and Alice only needs to transmit the files whose hashes Bob doesn't already have.